# Combinations question: choose number of balls to give a desired probability of winning?

Tags: combinations

Let's say I have a lottery where each player chooses 6 unique balls.

There are 5000 players.

How do I choose the number of balls so that there's a ~95% probability of winning???

I can do this by using the following function:

```
function getRange(int nEntries){
    int nBalls=6;
    while(nCr(nBalls,6)<nEntries){
      nBalls=nBalls+1;
    }
    return nBalls;
}
```

, however this is searching rather than working it out ;( I would like to make this function more efficient as I'm on a very constrained computer and this function will be called a lot.

Comment: choose, randomly, a $95$% of the different balls, then you have a probability of $95$% of winning.

Comment: $\;n=15\;$ is pretty close to solve $\;\binom n6\approx5,000\;$ , but the estimmation is by hand...

Comment: The number of entries will change. I need to be able to change the number of balls to give 95% chance ;(